# Creating activity where a user can send request to the another user to personal chat

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an activity where a user can send request to the other user for personal chat. When the user sends the request, the text on the button should change to cancel but it dint work. There is a slight logical problem that is causing lots of trouble. I have provided my code below which contains errors.

```
rootref.child(currentUserid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userid)){
            String request_type = dataSnapshot.child(userid).child("Request").getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(findFriend.this,request_type,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (request_type.equals("sent")){
                findfriendviewholder.request.setText("Cancel");
                findfriendviewholder.currentState = "request_sent";
            }
        }else{
            if(!currentUserid.equals(userid)) {
                findfriendviewholder.request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        findfriendviewholder.request.setEnabled(false);
                        if (findfriendviewholder.currentState.equals("new")){
                            rootref.child("Friends").child(currentUserid).child(userid).child("Request").setValue("sent")
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                rootref.child("Friends").child(userid).child(currentUserid).child("Request").setValue("Recived").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                            findfriendviewholder.request.setEnabled(true);
                                                            findfriendviewholder.request.setText("Cancel");
                                                            findfriendviewholder.currentState = "reques_sent";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                findfriendviewholder.request.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). In a meanwhile, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer, but way to find root cause for it.

1. Try to debug or put some logcat after each task and find whether
   task is successful first, second requests.
2. Check if you have all the child root names matching the key as you configured.
3. Verify if userid, currentUserid passed doesn't have a null value or
   incorrect value

You have a spelling mistake in word "Recived" == Received. check if that is correct.